# how to get magento button style?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, template

I have created some form that opens in new popup window. And there i have some text, combo box and buttons and i would like to add to these buttons magento button style, but how can get this style?

My created form lays in there: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mycompany/label.phtml

```
<html>
                   <h2>Select label size:</h2>        
                    <form action="LebelController.php" method="POST"><div>
                        <select name="SIZE">
                                 <option value="1x5">1x5</option>
                                  <option value="15x10">15x10</option>
                                  <option value="15x37">15x37</option>
                                  <option value="70x42">70x42</option>

                                </select>
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()?>" name="form_key">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" style="width: 100px; height:40px; font-size: 130%;"></p>
                        </form>
                   </html>
```

And this is my app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml file

```
<mymodule_label_setlabel translate=”label”>
        <label>Label</label>
        <reference name=”root”></reference>
        <reference name=”content”>
            <block type=”mymodule/block_labelblock” name=”mymodule.labelblock” template=”mymodule/label.phtml”/>
        </reference>
 </mymodule_label_setlabel>
```

and finally this is my controller that opens in new window and shows my form:
app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/controllers/Adminhtml/LabelController.php

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_LabelController
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function setlabelAction()
        {
$output = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('mycomapny/label.phtml')->toHtml();
                $this->getResponse()->appendBody($output);
}
```

i am wondering how can i add magento style to this button, if i could add also combo box magento style that would be also great. So how can i get this magento style for buttons?
p.s. this all happens in backend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$button = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button');
$button->setData(array(
    'label' => $this->__('Some label'),
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class' => 'button'
));

echo $button->toHtml();
```

Comment: i added your suggestion in label.phtml file, size is right but it is still in grey color with black letters, i just want it to be nice and orange with white letters

Comment: You can do it where ever you want. This will just generate the html for the button. I also added some class on it.

Comment: ok, but how can i get css to make this button orange with white letters?

Comment: @user6398. It should be orange if it's in the backend

Comment: @user6398. If you are using it in a popup, make sure that the all the css files are included in your page. Specially `boxes.css`

Comment: problem solved, i added this to my label.phtml file and everythink looks nice. Thank you Marius! `<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('boxes.css') ?>" media="all" />
 </head>`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question correct.

Magento buttons are build this way:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>" class="button" onclick="billing.save()">
    <span>
        <span>
            <?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>
        </span>
    </span>
</button>
```

So `<button>` and then two `<span>` inside.

Was this your question?

Comment: not sure if we understand each other, but my question is how to add magento style for button, like when i open link **track order** in sales, orders, specific order view, track order - to see tracking information, there is white screen with magento buttons and text. I tried your suggestion, and button become exactly in size like other magento buttons in backend but it still has ugly grey color